# Getting Count grouped by ID in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, count

I know their are extensive amount of answers and questions related to count, I just can't find the one I am looking for. I have a dataset about employment history and I need to see How many times the number 1 appears by ID grouped by manager.

DF

```
 ID      Date    Job     Manager     Full-Time
 101   05/2022   Sales     103         1
 101   06/2022   Sales     103         1
 102   08/2022   Tech      105         0
 102   09/2022   Tech      105         1
 103   11/2021   Sales     110         0
 104   04/2022   Sales     103         0
 104   05/2022   Sales     103         1
 104   06/2022   Sales     103         1
 104   07/2022   Sales     103         1
 104   08/2022   Sales     103         0
 ......
 201   10/2022   HR        198         1
```

What I want is a count of the not how many 1s an ID has but how many IDs have a 1 in their history grouped to the manager they belong to.

Desired Output

```
Manager     Full-Time Count 
  103              2
  105              1
  110              3
  ....
  198      `        2
```

I tried using `df['FT Count'] df.groupby('Manager')['Full-Time'].nunique`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do:

```py
x = df[df['Full-Time'].eq(1)].groupby('ID')['ID'].count()
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
ID
101    2
102    1
104    3
201    1
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

---

Or using `.pivot_table`:

```
x = df.pivot_table(index='ID', values='Full-Time', aggfunc='sum')
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
     Full-Time
ID            
101          2
102          1
103          0
104          3
201          1
```

Comment: This is kinda what I want is grouped by manager but I just had to change the field used.